# How do I print the text in between a span tag using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I've been playing around with Nokogiri on Ruby recently, and I've run into a problem where when I want to puts a specific item to the console, but it prints out blank spaces only.  I've tried puts other text to the console such as the products names and that works fine.  So I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the code.

```
url = "https://www.ikea.com/us/en/search/?query=chair"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css('.prodHeader').each do |item|
  price = item.css('span#txtPrice').text
  puts price
end
```

Heres the HTML block I'm referencing.

```
<span id="txtPriceProduct1" class="prodPrice" style="clear:both;">
            $89.00              
        </span>
```

Comment: `txtPrice` doesn't seem to appear in the HTML you've shown

Comment: Did you try running the code?

Comment: That should be: `#txtPriceProduct1`

Answer (score 0):

The element with id `#txtPriceProduct1` is a sibling of `.prodHeader`, not a child. Your code only searches through the children of `.prodHeader`, that’s why the element containing the price is not found.

This code prints out all the prices (stripped of whitespace):

```
doc.css('.prodHeader').each do |item|
  price = item.next_element.text
  puts price.strip
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing empty lines because there is no matching node `span#txtPrice`, causing it to return empty `NodeSet`, calling `text` on which returns empty string. 
You might want to do:

```
doc.css('.prodHeader').each do |item|
  puts "#{item.css('.prodName').text.strip} - #{item.css('+ span').text.strip}"
end

LÅNGFJÄLL - $149.00
IKEA PS LÖMSK - $69.99
LANGUR - $119.00
HATTEFJÄLL - $249.00
EKERÖ - $179.00
NORRARYD - $99.00
HATTEFJÄLL - $219.00
POÄNG - $79.00
HENRIKSDAL - $69.00
VÄNNÄS - $449.00
SJÄLLAND - $95.00
TULLSTA - $149.00
LÅNGFJÄLL - $179.00
BERNHARD - $169.00
POÄNG - $129.00
SJÄLLAND - $95.00
POÄNG - $129.00
INDUSTRIELL - $149.00
INDUSTRIELL - $89.00
LÅNGFJÄLL - $199.00
TULLSTA - $30.00
UTTRAN - $599.00
FJÄLLBERGET - $199.00
STRANDMON - $99.00
EKERÖ - $149.00
```

In above, we are getting `.prodHeader` and extracting the product name with the child selector, and extracting the price with `+ span` using sibling selector